# The game will quit after click the admob's ad

Tags: android, admob

I am writing a game and add the admob (version 6.4.1). When click the AD, it will have two problem and I don't know how to solve or debug.

I am using following code to add admob to surfaceview. Basically, it refered to other post at here.

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "My_ID");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
adView.setLayoutParams(lp);
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.addView(new MySurfaceViewX(this));
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
setContentView(layout);
```

Following is the logcat information:

```
06-25 15:08:24.214: I/System.out(25294): Pause all Music
06-25 15:08:24.218: I/System.out(25294): onPause
06-25 15:08:25.007: I/Ads(25294): onPresentScreen()
06-25 15:08:25.007: I/System.out(25294): onPresentScreen
06-25 15:08:25.148: I/Ads(25294): onLeaveApplication()
06-25 15:08:25.148: I/System.out(25294): onLeaveApplication
06-25 15:08:25.273: I/System.out(25294): SurfaceDestoryed
06-25 15:08:25.402: I/System.out(25294): onStop (Game exit temperory and AD is running)
06-25 15:08:28.261: D/webviewglue(25294): OnTrimMemory with EGL Context 0x0
06-25 15:08:28.308: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:28.308: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:28.308: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:28.308: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:28.308: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:32.652: D/webviewglue(25294): OnTrimMemory with EGL Context 0x0
06-25 15:08:32.656: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:32.656: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:32.656: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:32.656: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:32.656: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:35.789: I/Ads(25294): onDismissScreen()
06-25 15:08:35.800: I/System.out(25294): onDismissScreen
06-25 15:08:35.960: I/System.out(25294): onRestart
06-25 15:08:35.960: I/System.out(25294): onResume
06-25 15:08:36.035: I/System.out(25294): SurfaceCreated
06-25 15:08:36.050: I/System.out(25294): surfaceChanged 
06-25 15:08:39.722: I/System.out(25294): Pause all Music (when press "Back" key, it will go to  background at here)
06-25 15:08:39.722: I/System.out(25294): onPause
06-25 15:08:40.164: I/System.out(25294): SurfaceDestoryed
06-25 15:08:41.285: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25294): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-25 15:08:42.621: D/webviewglue(25294): OnTrimMemory with EGL Context 0x0
06-25 15:08:42.621: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:42.621: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:42.625: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:42.625: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:42.625: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-25 15:08:42.636: I/System.out(25294): onStop
06-25 15:08:42.699: E/webview(25294): Error: WebView.destroy() called while still attached!
06-25 15:08:42.699: D/webviewglue(25294): nativeDestroy view: 0x52039c80
06-25 15:08:42.703: I/System.out(25294): onDestory
```

Problems :

1) When the AD clicked, the google play or explorer will be running. Logcat will have following error appear.

```
06-25 15:08:41.285: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25294): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-25 15:08:42.621: D/webviewglue(25294): OnTrimMemory with EGL Context 0x0
06-25 15:08:42.621: E/libEGL(25294): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

2) When press "Back" key and return to game, if press "Back" key again, the game will goto background. It likes to use finish() or press "Home" key. The game not crash and it can call back after press the icon again.

If I haven't click the AD, everything is running OK.

I also found if it run at emulator, it will not have above ERROR.

Please , Who can help me? it make me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably allowing your EGL Surface and context to be used by more than one thread.  Android requires that all calls to OpenGL ES for a given context must come from only a single thread.  This article explains in detail:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1/

Comment: But my game is not 3D Game, does it will use openGL?

Comment: Since the ICS version, Android uses OpenGL ES 2.0 by default.  Since you said it works on the AVD emulator, the problem may be that the OpenGL ES or EGL driver on your device has bugs.  What is the device?  Try a different one.

Comment: What type of GPU does the Aurora 2 have?  Does it work better than the Samsung?  If so, than I think your problem is probably a bug in Samsung's drivers.